# SQL query for matching multiple values in the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL as follows.

```
Id   Designation           Years          Employee
1    Soft.Egr            2000-2005           A
2    Soft.Egr            2000-2005           B
3    Soft.Egr            2000-2005           C
4    Sr.Soft.Egr         2005-2010           A
5    Sr.Soft.Egr         2005-2010           B
6    Pro.Mgr             2010-2012           A
```

I need to get the Employees who worked as Soft.Egr and Sr.Soft.Egr and Pro.Mgr. It is not possible to use IN or Multiple ANDs in the query. How to do this??

Comment: You have to use `self join` to get you desired result. Refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you might actually be looking for is [relational division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), even if your exercise requirements forbid using `AND` (for whatever reason?). This is tricky, but possible to express correctly in SQL.

Relational division in prosa means: Find those employees who have a record in the employees table for all existing designations. Or in SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E1.Employee FROM Employees E1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Employees E2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Employees E3
        WHERE E3.Employee = E1.Employee
        AND E3.Designation = E2.Designation
    )
)
```

To see the above query in action, consider this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23909/1)

A good resource explaining relational division can be found here:
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division

Comment: we don't know for sure that these are all the possible designations, these are just the ones in the example - interesting solution nonetheless!

Comment: @ninesided: I know, you're probably right. But I have a gut feeling (since this is an academic question), that this could be about relational division. And if it's not, it's still good to raise relational division awareness on Stack Overflow :-)

Answer (score 47):

One way:

```
select Employee
from job_history
where Designation in ('Soft.Egr','Sr.Soft.Egr','Pro.Mgr')
group by Employee
having count(distinct Designation) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get additional information back about each of the roles (like the dates) then joining back to your original table for each of the additional designations is a possible solution:

```
SELECT t.Employee, t.Designation, t.Years, t1.Designation, t1.Years, t2.Designation, t2.Years
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN t2 ON (t2.Employee = t.Employee AND t2.Designation = 'Sr.Soft.Egr')
INNER JOIN t3 ON (t3.Employee = t.Employee AND t3.Designation = 'Soft.Egr')
WHERE t.Designation = 'Pro.Mgr';
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not the following (for postgresql)?

```
SELECT employee FROM Employees WHERE Designation ='Sr.Soft.Egr'
INTERSECT 
SELECT employee FROM Employees WHERE Designation ='Soft.Egr'
INTERSECT 
SELECT employee FROM Employees WHERE Designation ='Pro.Mgr'
```

Link to [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d3ab6/9/0)

I know this might not optimized, but I find this much much easier to understand and modify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.employee, 
                t1.designation 
FROM tempEmployees t1, tempEmployees t2, tempEmployees t3 
WHERE t1.employee = t2.employee AND
      t2.employee = t3.employee AND 
      t3.employee = t1.employee AND
      t1.designation != t2.designation AND 
      t2.designation != t3.designation AND 
      t3.designation != t1.designation
```